# JavaScript to display asp:TextBox based on selected option

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I just recently started developing some parts of the ASP.NET project but I have very little experience of it. The problem is pretty much as described in a title of this question and here goes the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/hide.fields.js"></script>   

<divs and divs...>

<asp:DropDownList class="dropdown expand" ID="EligibleUK" onchange="visaCheck(this.ListItem.GetValue());" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem
                            Enabled="True"
                            Text="Choose..."
                            Value=""
                        />
                        <asp:ListItem
                            Enabled="True"
                            Text="Yes (UK/EU Cittizen)"
                            Value="Yes (UK/EU Cittizen)"
                        />
                        <asp:ListItem
                            Enabled="True"
                            Text="Yes (Work Visa)"
                            Value="Yes (Work Visa)"
                        />
                        <asp:ListItem
                            Enabled="True"
                            Text="No"
                            Value="No"
                        />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

the content of my JS file:

```
function visaCheck(visa) {
if (visa === "Yes (Work Visa)"){
    document.getElementById(visa1).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(visa2).style.display = "block";
}else{
    document.getElementById(visa1).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(visa2).style.display = "none";
}
```

}

Now I tried different things in the html (.master strictly speaking) where I call the JS function code, such as:

```
this.ListItem
asp:ListItem
ListItem.Value
this.ListItem.Value
this.ListItem.Value()
this.ListItem.GetValue()
```

including the most obvious one (this.value) which worked with standard html file and in jsfiddle. Is there any specific way of doing it in ASP.NET? What am I missing and how do I fix this problem? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
<asp:DropDownList class="dropdown expand" ID="EligibleUK" onchange="visaCheck(this.options[this.selectdIndex].value);" runat="server">
```

Comment: well this didn't work, BUT I called the function with no argument and used the clue you gave me to modify JS function and it works so thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

I post an answer under my own question so it's more visible. I call js function with no argument and my javascript looks like this now:

```
function visaCheck() {
var visa = document.getElementById('Content_EligibleUK');
var selectedIndex = visa.selectedIndex;
var value = visa.options[selectedIndex].value

if (value === "Yes (Work Visa)"){
    document.getElementById("visa1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("visa2").style.display = "block";
}else{
    document.getElementById("visa1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("visa2").style.display = "none";
}
```

}

hope this helps some folks in the future :)